# What are the rules for writing ци or цы in Russian?

Tags: правописание

ц is an always-hard consonant. Yet in some cases it is followed by и while in other cases - with ы. Consider цыган vs Ельцин vs. Курицын. What are the general rules?

Answer (score 3):

[The rule](http://dictionary.liferus.ru/dictionary_3.htm) is rather simple. In the root of a word, usually `ци` is written, `цы` is written only in the following words and in all their derivatives:

> цыган, цыпленок, цыпочки, цыц

which can be easily remembered with the help of this mnemonic sentence:

> Цыган на цыпочках цыкнул цыплёнку: "Цыц!"

In the suffixes and endings, `цы` can appear when the suffix `-ын` and the adjectival ending `-ый` are added after `ц`:

> Синицын, Курицына
>
> куцый, бледнолицый

And also `цы` appears when the ending `-и / -ы` is added after the words with stems ending in `-ц` (after `-ц` which is always 'hard', non-palatalized, it is always `-ы`):

> Молодцы, красавцы, отцы

---

**Note 1:** There are [no specific rules that apply to surnames](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%C5%EB%FC%F6%E8%ED), each surname must be written exactly as it is written in the person's passport. That is why the surname `Ельцин` is written with `и`, one more famous idiosyncratic surname is `Вицин`.

**Note 2:** In the texts printed in the first half of the 20th century and earlier, `цы` can appear in other roots, too: `цыгарка`, `цымбалы`, `цыбуля`, etc., but that is obsolete spelling, these words are written with `ци` now.

Comment: Why is Ельцин then?

Comment: @Anixx - There are [no rules](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%C5%EB%FC%F6%E8%ED) that apply to surnames, each surname must be written exactly as it is written in the person's passport. One more surname that is idiosyncratic is Вицин. I'll add that to my answer.